# Why is the value null when using session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a ASP.net website which is located in one of my server and I am accessing the site from a local PC on the same network. When the application runs, it saves a PDF file in the `C:\PDFFolder` folder. I want to display a link so the user can download the file in the local PC from the server.

I am using a session variable for the filename:

```
string strFileName = "completed_pdf_" + k + ".pdf"; //k is a variable within the function
Session["fileName"] = strFileName;
```

In the server the folder where the files are stored is: `C:\PDFFolder\{filename}.pdf`
From the local PC to access that file is: `\\myserver\PDFFolder\{filename}.pdf`

The code for the DOWNLOAD button is:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(Session["pathName"].ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(Session["fileName"].ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(Path.Combine(@"C:\PDFGenerate", Session["fileName"].ToString()).ToString());
        Response.Redirect("DownloadFilePDF.ashx?myvar=" + Session["fileName"].ToString());
    }
```

On the button to download the file, I fire a `HttpHandler` function onclick:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DownloadFilePDF" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class DownloadFilePDF : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        System.Web.HttpRequest request2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string strSessVar2 = request2.QueryString["fileName"];

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        byte[] fileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"C:\PDFGenerate", strSessVar2));
        response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.pdf", strSessVar2));
        response.BinaryWrite(fileByteArray);
        response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error on this line: `byte[] fileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"C:\PDFGenerate", strSessVar2));`

The error is: `Value cannot be null`

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: does changing "DownloadFilePDF.ashx?myvar=" to "DownloadFilePDF.ashx?fileName=" fix it?

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using `response.WriteFile`? Does the account that is running the web application have permissions to read this shared directory?

Comment: @dom BubbleHearth answered it but you said it first!!!

Comment: yea my recommendation was kindly moved to a comment. boo.

Comment: I did upvote your comment... +2? :P

Comment: Thank you kindly.  I guess time I need to be demanding, rather than inquisitive lol.

Comment: Follow your guts and I never downvote just because it is something that wasn't requested. Someone made the effort to respond. I simply state it in the comment. BTW you can still answer and I can UPVOTE and you get +5!

Comment: Your code is wide open to an attack of the form: DownloadFilePDF.ashx?myvar=../Windows/someimportantfile.ini  This would allow a malicious attacker to download any file on your server

Comment: @MarkPeters Oh man, how so?

Comment: @SiKni8 see edited comment.  Also, Never, ever, trust what's in the query string

Comment: I see your point but I am using a session and when I tried to navigate to that link you mentioned my website just showed an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is this line:

```
string strSessVar2 = request2.QueryString["fileName"];
```

You want to get the value of `myvar`:

```
string strSessVar2 = request2.QueryString["myvar"];
```